# Node.js or Go for Hyperledger Fabric's chaincode development?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

Which language among `Node.js` and `Go` is better suited for 'chaincode' development when it comes to maintainibility, scalability and better support?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a matter of personal preference, but I'd say Golang, because:

- Node.js chaincode uses npm install at the time of container building, which is slow and might fail due to network problems, while Golang just compiles the source code without fetching anything.
- Chaincode features are introduced to Golang chaincode first and then later on to other chaincode implementations.

Comment: Do you have a detailed comparison, a article or something?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Comment: [They may add packaging option in future](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-9287), fyi

Comment: I agree with @yacovm, and I'd also add a third reason: docker images size for chaincode are a lot bigger with nodejs than with go, in a 1:8 factor (180MB in Go vs 1.5GB in nodejs). If you need to test a network with several peers or several chaincodes interacting, you'll have to wait minutes and minutes between each network relaunch. A pain.

Comment: @jfc thanx for your response. I wanted to know if this is still the case and if yes, what would be the workaround to solve it. I am currently working with composer and when I try to deploy a new bna to upgrade the network logic, it takes a quite long time for the corresponding peer (dev.peer...) to restart. would it help if I implement the network business logic using native chaincodes written in Go, while using Transaction processors of composer to invoke the native chaincodes?