# Hyperledger Fabric Chaincode Development Language - NodeJS, Java, or Go?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

With consideration of existing functionality, developer productivity (assuming minimal experience in each language), support within the Fabric community, and roadmap for enhancements, is there any chaincode development language that should be preferred as the short-term and, perhaps separately, as the long-term choice?

Prior question [Node.js or Go for Hyperledger Fabric's chaincode development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53301415/node-js-or-go-for-hyperledger-fabrics-chaincode-development) did not address Java as an option, and does not account for recent Fabric 1.4 platform release.

Comment: This just depends on your choice, there are many documentations on each language and communities are now bigger than ever. Start with the language you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Hyperledger Fabric v1.4, there is base functional parity between Go, Node.js, and Java chaincode.

The previous answer in [Node.js or Go for Hyperledger Fabric's chaincode development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53301415/node-js-or-go-for-hyperledger-fabrics-chaincode-development) is still fundamentally true. Base features typically get delivered in Go chaincode first. That being said, a new programming model has been introduced to Node.js chaincode in v1.4 that is explained in the new [Developing Applications documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developapps/developing_applications.html). If the new programming model is of interest to you, Node.js chaincode would be a good choice.

At the end of the day, each of the languages have similar function, similar performance, as well as good support and community adoption.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a roadmap of chaincode features for currently planned releases and when they would be available in the various language chaincode shims? For example, if HLF v2.0 is going to have new chaincode features A and B but those are only available in Go shim with that release, than that would be very useful information.