# is it good to develop a hyperledger fabric chaincode using go sdk?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I need to develop one project on **hyperledger-fabric** using a **GO SDK**. But as per the latest release `GO SDKs` that have not yet been officially released.

I had gone through with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54603029/hyperledger-fabric-chaincode-development-language-nodejs-java-or-go) post. But still, is it better to use a `Go-SDK` for any development of the product? So anyone knows it's products or web projects which are in used?

Answer (score 0):

From the chat of the go-sdk-fabric:

> fabric-sdk-go is stable. The reason that still in beta just for missing some documentation

The package works but it is kind of a mess, the only documentation are the chainhero example, the test files and the go-doc. There are a lot of package and some of them seems to do the same but they're not always compatible with each other.

Comment: Matias Diaz, Thank you for your response. But in short, we can't use Go SDK in product development, we have to wait for an alpha release?

Comment: Is still in beta, but is stable, only not well documented. If you can use it or not depends on your production policy. 

If you are not sure you can ask in their [rocket chat](https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-sdk-go).

Comment: @Isha you can use it in Production. Use `https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/tree/v1.0.0-alpha5`  version. Currently they are adding the `fabric v2` support in the `master(v1.0.0.0-beta1)` hence it is not stable but `alpha5` is perfectly fine.